# django 1.10 Application level URL does not recognize positional parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to employ positional parameters on a view inside one app of my django application.

The app is called member.  and the member/urls.py is called by the project trekfed:

### trekfed.py

```
from member import urls as mviews
from public import views as pviews

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^member/', include(mviews)),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

### member\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', views.index, name='myprofile'),
    url(r'^(?P<mbr>)/$', views.index, name='profile'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

### views.py

```
@login_required
def index(request, mbr=""):

    print(mbr)
    data = {}
    if mbr:
        user = User.objects.filter(Q(id=mbr)|Q(username=mbr)).values('User_id')
    else:
        user = request.user
    data['user'] = user
    data['member'] = models.Member.objects.get(User=user)
    data['Address'] = models.Address.objects.filter(User=user).get(Primary=True)
    data['Phone'] = models.Phone.objects.filter(User=user).get(Primary=True)
    data['Family'] = models.Family.objects.filter(Primary=user.member)
    data['Sponsor'] = models.Family.objects.filter(Dependent=user.member.pk)
    data['rank'] = models.Promotion.objects.filter(User=user).latest('Date_Effective')
    return render(request, "member/profile/page_user_profile.html", data)
```

when authenticated, if I go to `http://localhost:8000/member/` I can see my profile.  No problems.

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/member/user2/`  I still see my profile, not user2's.

Is there something that I'm missing here?  Thanks.

## Update 1

Tried:

```
url(r'^(?P<mbr>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.index, name='profile'),
```

and

```
url(r'^(?P<mbr>.+)/$', views.index, name='profile'),
```

with no change.

Comment: Probably your `mbr` stays `""` in the process...

Comment: ok.  how do I make it an optional field?

Comment: @arcee123  you don't need to make it an optional field, the first element of urlpatterns (i.e. end-of-line `$`) will match first if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is something you're missing here and it's called [`regex pattern`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example).

In your `urls` the `url(r'^(?P<mbr>)/$'),` pattern does not matches anything (it's just an empty string, `''`). You should first think of what pattern you want to capture (say only words, only digits, both words and digits, both word and digits and `-`, both words and digits and `-` and `_` etc.

It all depends on the captured pattern. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/common_url_regex.md) for some common url patterns and whatever you choose, place it after the `>` character (`url(r'^(?P<mbr>regex_pattern_here)/$'),`).

If you want to make it an optional field then you still have to enter a regex pattern (in case something matches) and leave your `urls` as is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='myprofile'),
    url(r'^(?P<mbr>regex_pattern_here)/$', views.index, name='profile'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

With this approach, both `http://localhost:8000/member/` (without an `mbr`) and `http://localhost:8000/member/user2/` (with `mbr = user2`) will hit the `views.index` view.

[BONUS]: You can test your regex patterns in http://pythex.org/

Comment: This is right - no regex specified!  However, as soon as the user corrects that, they are going to have a new problem: the object returned from the filter will be a `ValuesQuerySet` instead of a user object.

Comment: @wim. Yes. You're right. Do you suggest to update my answer or leave it as is and a new question should be created for that?

Comment: ok.  I tried the above.  no change.  Thanks for helping...do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What regex_pattern_here did you use?

Comment: I put it up in the Update #1.